# Automatic re-adding default gateway for NIC in Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, routing, windows-10, static-routes

I have a problem with odd behaviour with gateway settings being auto-added.

I have two integrated NICs on my windows 10 PC with same gateway IP address.

One NIC is for ATM KVM (Intel VPRO), second for Internet.

So I want to make only second interface work with internet. Of course I'm able to change the metric to reach that goal but I want just to remove the gateway from first NIC. But somehow after removing it it is being re-added  back again.

I've tried all I could, including such power-shell commands as:

```
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex "5" -RouterDiscovery disabled
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex "5" -AdvertiseDefaultRoute disabled
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex "5" -IgnoreDefaultRoutes disabled
```

But nothing I have tried has worked.

Maybe someone knows what's the problem or it's just a feature of the operating system?

Comment: Is the KVM NIC a real NIC or a software construction provided by Intel drivers?

Comment: Are you using DHCP or static IP addressing? If you're using DHCP, do you have access to the server?